# Homebrew version of vim won't open files

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I installed vim via `brew` so I could have the latest version (7.4) and get syntax highlighting for Clojure. No big deal. Unfortunately, the brew version of vim seems to be broken on my system. I also aliased the `vim` command:

```
brew install vim # Install went successfully
alias vim=/usr/local/Cellar/7.4.052/bin/vim # Shouldn't be any problems here
```

When I open the brew version of vim, it fails to load any of my plugins (I use [spf13](http://vim.spf13.com)) throwing a bunch of "Undefined variable" and "Invalid expression", etc errors for every plugin in my bundle directory; I just hit enter to continue. My `.vimrc` loads properly. When I open a file, it opens two tabs, both blank. One is a new file, the other is the file I tried to open, except there's nothing in it.

Potentially useful information: `echo $VIM` returns an empty line, while `echo $ZSH` returns `/User/bsima/.dotfiles` as expected.

Here are [my dotfiles](http://github.com/bsima/dotfiles), but I don't think the problem lies in those configuration files.

**Is this a known bug? Or is something wrong with my vim install?**

I have no idea what's going on and I really miss my vim :( As good as Textmate is, I can't be without vim forever.

**Edit:** MacVim, installed via Homebrew, *kinda* works. It still opens 2 tabs on startup, but it does open files for editing and saves.

Comment: Does vim work when run with `vim -u NONE`

Comment: Yes, `vim -u NONE` works. It opens version 7.4, the Homebrew version. I can even `:open project.clj` and turn on syntax highlighting and stuff. Also, `which vim` returns `/usr/local/bin/vim`, but running just `vim project.clj` still causes the error described above.

Comment: So the problem is with your configuration. `vim -u NONE` runs vim without your vimrc and plugins

Comment: I was afraid of that. So I have to go through all of my plugins, deactivate, test, etc... ugh.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is with pathogen. I don't think it's loading properly, thus none of my plugins are loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: it was with my spf13 vim config. The following commands fixed the issue, in addition to double-checking that symlinks such as `~/.vim` and `~/.vimrc` were correct:

```
> which vim # This should output /usr/local/bin/vim since I'm using Homebrew
/usr/local/bin/vim
> cd ~/.spf13-vim-3
> ./bootstrap.sh # Basically re-installs spf13
```

Comment: Why not take this opportunity to remove spf13 definitely and do *your* configuration *yourself*? Also, read `:help :open`.

Comment: I did that once. I actually like spf13 better than what I came up with. When I have a bit of extra time I'll tackle that and customize spf13's template to my liking, but for now it works for me.